# Direct connection to another PC while connected to Wi-Fi

Tags: networking, windows-10, home-networking

I have 2 Windows 10 PCs connected to the same Wi-Fi network in the same room. I regularly need to access file shares on PC1 from PC2 and vice versa, being on Wi-Fi this is very slow.

I'd like to create a direct ethernet connection between the two (in order to speed up file sharing) whilst maintaining the Wi-Fi connection for internet connectivity.

I've tried various configurations in `Network Connections` with the bridge adapter to no avail. Results end up breaking internet connectivity for one or both of the machines, or breaking the direct connection between the two.

Is there a way to do this without buying a router to create a second network between to two computers? Unfortunately these PCs are too far away from any network ports to the current router.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Losing internet when connecting two PC's trough an Ethernet cable](https://superuser.com/questions/1165708/losing-internet-when-connecting-two-pcs-trough-an-ethernet-cable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution you are most likely looking for is:

1. (Assuming at least 1 of the computers has a Gigabit ethernet connection) is connect the 2 computers together via a regular ethernet cable.  If this does not work - generally only applicable to some slower cards - you would need to get or make a crossover ethernet cable, which reverses the send and receive pairs on 1 side.
2. Allocate each ethernet interface a static IP address in the same range.  This range needs to be DIFFERENT to the range that WIFI uses.  Assuming your WIFI uses 192.168.1.x, you could use 10.0.1.x (or vice-versa). DO NOT SPECIFY A DEFAULT GATEWAY FOR THE ETHERNET CONNECTIONS.

When sharing traffic on the ethernet interface, refer to the computers by the ethernet interface IP address.  (You may need to use \10.0.1.1\fileshare if using file sharing for example)